# "Missing protocol 'ProtoGenesis' for the current block" when I launch a node

Tags: node, public-node

"Missing protocol 'ProtoGenesis' for the current block" when I launch a node, the version is the newest.
[image]
[image]

Comment: What network are you trying to connect to?

Answer (score 0):

I think i've seen this screenshots already at the baker slack or riot.

This should solve the "problem":

```
git checkout mainnet && git pull && make build-deps && eval $(opam env) && make
```